Crossing the Irish border with my non-EU citizen spouse
I'll be traveling to Ireland this fall. I'm an Irish citizen, but I'll be traveling with my American spouse. Can we use the EU line, or do we need to use the non-EU line at passport control?

Why all the downvotes?

Does this answer your question? EU citizen and non-EU spouse entering the EU (Schengen area)

@Relaxed I wasn’t one of the down voters, but perhaps it was because this question pops up fairly regularly. I couldn’t find the dup when I searched, however now it’s been highlighted here I have added it to the Schengen Community Wiki for future reference

@Traveller Actually, it's subtle but this question hasn't come up as far as I know and I personally do not know the answer. The question listed is most definitely not a duplicate. It's easy to deal with the case of Irish citizens entering the Schengen area (Schengen Borders code) and other EU citizens entering Ireland (Freedom of Movement directive) but Ireland is not in the Schengen area and freedom of movement rights do not by default apply to your own country. EU law does not apply here.

So the question is whether Irish law mandates anything. Beyond the legal question, it would also be useful to get some direct experience on eGates at Irish airports (as these do not seem to support non-EU passports for entry and are often deployed to replace “EU passports” queues) and whether Irish border guards care at all (they might not).

@Relaxed I see your point. In which case perhaps this is relevant, it mentions non-EU/Schengen citizens need to receive an Irish entry stamp, which would rule out using the eGates?

@Eric B For completeness, will you arrive into Ireland via the UK, or direct?

No idea, but assuming you're flying into Dublin, I'd email border control and ask (bmu@justice.ie)

@Traveller Irrelevant; Ireland performs full checks if flying from the UK (at least at Dublin and Kerry airport); it's only by sea that it's selective

Thanks all. Not sure why the down votes. I did search for the answer before I asked. I will be flying directly from the US. Judging from all the responses, it seems like each airport /border guard is different. I'll try emailing border control. Thanks for the link @Crazydre

@EricB could you post an answer describing their response?  Also note that in the Schengen area, there is no "non-EU" line, strictly speaking; it's an "all passports" line, so mixed parties are certainly supposed to be able to go together to that line even if they aren't accepted together in the EU line.  I don't know how Ireland handles this, though.

Border Control was quick to respond, but didn't answer the question. They just gave me the same general information I have found elsewhere. I still don't know which line we should use. I guess I will find out when we get there.

@phoog At Dublin it's "EU/EEA/CH/UK" and "Non-EU"
